# Random amount of pictures when clicking a button

Tags: javascript

i have an assignment were i need to create a function that when i click a button it needs to generate a random amount of pictures

```js
var addImgBtn = document.getElementById("add-img-btn");
var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output-div");

function addImg() {
  outputDiv.innerHTML = `
    <img src="img/mann.jpg"/>
  `;
}

function addRandomImg() {
  addImgBtn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
}

addImgBtn.onclick = addImg;
```

```html
<input id="add-img-btn" type="button" value="Legg til bilde" />
<div id="output-div"></div>
```

Comment: What's your question? Does your code work? If not have you debugged it to find out where the error is?

Comment: My code does not work, i have tried to debug it, the point is that i need the code to write out a random number of pictures from 1 to 100 of the same picture when i click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point you need to do some iteration to build up the HTML that contains all of the images.

1. Your `onclick` should be calling `addRandomImg`.
2. You should be assigning the result of the randomiser to a new variable, not `addImgBtn`.
3. Use a `for...loop` to iterate between 0 and `rnd`, and on each iteration push the image HTML into an array. Once all iterations are complete you can finally update `outputDiv` with that HTML making sure you [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) up the elements of the array into a string.

```js
var addImgBtn = document.getElementById("add-img-btn");
var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output-div");

function addRandomImg() {
  const rnd = addImgBtn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  let html = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= rnd; i++) {
    html.push('<img src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff"/>');
  }
  outputDiv.innerHTML = html.join('');
}

addImgBtn.onclick = addRandomImg;
```

```css
img { margin: 2px 2px; }
```

```html
<input id="add-img-btn" type="button" value="Legg til bilde" />
<div id="output-div"></div>
```